# How to create a python function passing an information to refer a case

Tags: python, function

I would like to create a function where we can specify an information as a string input. The result will be change by the information and an error might be raised if the information is not correct

i mean something like this small example :

```
def f(a,b,method='repartition uniforme'):
  if method=='repartition uniforme':
    return a+b
  if method=='repartition fin de ligne':
    return a*b
  else:
    raise NameError('méthode de répartition des charge non valide')
```

What is the best and proper way to create this kind of function ?

Comment: Is there a problem with the way you've currently created that kind of function?

Comment: If I were doing this, I would either keep the string very short (probably 6 or fewer characters) or I would use an `enum` to represent the different choices.  With a long string like this you increase the likelihood that the user will make a typo which will result in undesirable behavior.

Comment: I don't have any problem with the formulation but I just want to do it properly :)

Thanks 0x5453. I don't really what do you mean by enum but I would be happy to try it. Is where a tutorial or smth on the web ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine with one exception - NameError is usually reserved for namespace errors, while what you want is ValueError which is commonly used for argument values of correct type but outside of expected range.

Since Python 3.10 you can use match statements instead of chained 'if's to make it more readable. Your code would look like that using that syntax:

```
def f(a,b,method='repartition uniforme'):
    match method:
        case 'repartition uniforme':
            return a+b
        case 'repartition fin de ligne':
            return a*b
        case _:
            raise ValueError('méthode de répartition des charge non valide')
```

Comment: That seams great !
but I have a "invalid syntax error" with this code. Do you know where the problem is ?

Comment: @ThomasLESIEUR noticed the "Since Python 3.10..."?

Comment: I was pretty sure that i got 3.10
But indeed after verification, I don't ^^
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store your functions in a dictionary:

```py
funcs = {
    'repartition uniforme': lambda x, y: x + y,
    'repartition fin de ligne': lambda x, y: x * y
}

def f(a,b,method='repartition uniforme'):
    try:
        return funcs[method](a, b)
    except KeyError:
        raise NameError('méthode de répartition des charge non valide')
```